# Mongoose: how to call my functions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm unable to call the calc function. Why?

```
MyModel.find(
{
    $where: function() {
        return calc(this) > 500;
    }
},
function (err, results) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log(results);
});

function calc(obj) {
    return obj.x + obj.y;
}
```

Comment: Are these defined in the same file?

Comment: Yes they are in the same file

Answer (score 0):

The code of the `$where` is sent to the server for execution, so it can only reference functions within its own scope (as well as the built-in function listed [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#restrictions)).

So your code would have to be restructured with `calc` defined in scope:

```js
MyModel.find(
{
    $where: function() {
        function calc(obj) {
            return obj.x + obj.y;
        }
        return calc(this) > 500;
    }
},
function (err, results) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(results);
});
```